# Springboot application is able to fetch max 100 records only from keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, active-directory, keycloak

We have integrated springboot application with keycloak however we are able to poll only 100 records from keycloak and application does not throw any exception but we want all the records to be loaded in springboot application (which is around 10K) is there any configuration or sample code to do that ?

```
      UsersResource users = keycloak.realm(realm).users();
        log.info("Total user count from keycloak is " + users.count());
```

Keycloak should poll all the records available in Keycloak Db in springBoot class.Hoever it is only polling 100 records max in one go and returning response with success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you try:

```
List<UserRepresentation> results = keycloak.realm(realm).users().search(null, 0, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

There is default 100 for `Maximum results size` on the API level: See doc: https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/6.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource

Comment: Yes got the solution and agree with you on default 100 size. We have iterated as by getting Total size of users and processed them in chunk as below.                  int total  = keycloak.realm(realm).users().count()                                ; for (0 to to total){  keycloak.realm(realm).users().list(start ,batchEnd) //Process   }

Comment: Another question in same context would also need some thoughts [Mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58843079/how-to-read-events-for-newly-modified-record-from-keycloak-to-spring-boot)

Comment: The solution is good.