# How to read events for newly modified record from keycloak to spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak, spring-security-oauth2

Actually We have following flow and scenario to poll data in to my Spring boot App

Active Directory --> Keycloak --> Spring boot App

Here we are able to poll data in but in future if there is any record change in Active Directory keycloak has a provision to poll data in it's DB periodically but the same changed (Newly Added /Deleted /Updated ) records from key cloak to Spring boot application there is some eventing option but I do not see how and where to implement it ? 
I suppose there should be a listener in the spring boot application which would get triggered on any change in record (Newly Added /Deleted /Updated ) of keycloak

Answer (score 0):

The event listener is implemented on the Keycloak side. Here is an example of how to implement an event listener that logs events to console - [Event Listener Example](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/event-listener-sysout)

Instead of logging, you will need to send notifications to your SpringBoot application in any suitable way:

1. you can implement some endpoint in your SpringBoot application that will be invoked by Even Listener's code
2. or Event listener can send let's say JMS message and your SpringBoot application will be subscribed to the JMS topic
3. etc.

Comment: When you say "Event listener is implemented on the Keycloak side" but how and where do I write my custom logic to call my spring boot api when a user added/deleted/modified in keycloak? I am not quite sure where will SysoutEventListenerProvider.java resides or I need to add ? I do not see any provision on keycloak admin console to register SysoutEventListenerProvider?

Comment: If you follow the link and look at README there are instructions: 
 `you can deploy the example manually by copying the example's jar to:
 KEYCLOAK_HOME/standalone/deployments (for Linux)
 Then go to Events Config tab in the admin console and add sysout to Event Listeners.`